# OAuth2 Bearer Token not getting sent with RestSharp call

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, restsharp

Credentials are right, because I can get an `API response` using `PS` with the same `client id` and `secret`. The token isn't invalid, but it won't get attached correctly to the rest request

> Unauthorized. Access token is missing or invalid

Here's my code:

```
var client = new RestClient(url);
client.Authenticator = new OAuth2AuthorizationRequestHeaderAuthenticator("Bearer: " + OAuthToken);
var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
request.AddHeader("Accept", "application/json");

foreach (var paramName in parameters.Keys) {
    request.AddParameter(paramName, parameters[paramName]);
}

request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;

IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK) {
    string rawResponse = response.Content;
    dynamic deserializedResponse = new JsonDeserializer().Deserialize<dynamic>(response);
    return deserializedResponse;
}
else {
    Dictionary<string, string> returnData = new JsonDeserializer().Deserialize<Dictionary<string, string>>(response);
    throw new Exception("Failed call to API Management: " + string.Join(";", returnData));
 }
```

I've also tried using:

1. `request.AddHeader("authorization", "Bearer " + OAuthToken);`
2. `request.AddHeader("authorization", string.Format("Bearer " + OAuthToken));`
3. `request.AddHeader("authorization", string.Format("Bearer: " + OAuthToken));`
4. `request.AddHeader("authorization", $"Bearer {OAuthToken}");`
5. `request.AddParameter("authorization, "Bearer " + OAuthToken", HttpRequestHeader);`
6. `request.AddHeader("authorization", "bearer:" + access + "");`

None worked.

Comment: Whether the above mentioned code is token generated part?

Answer (score 3):

Following code worked for me:

```
var restClient = new RestClient(Url)
{
    Authenticator = new OAuth2AuthorizationRequestHeaderAuthenticator(accessToken, "Bearer")
};
```

As a result, the "Authorization" header will contain "Bearer {accessToken}"

Comment: Oh man on their website https://restsharp.dev/authenticators.html#access-token they provided a wrong example. That's why it didn't worked for me in the first place. Your example is correct. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I was not able to authenticate when I was using it like

`request.AddHeader("Authorization", $"Bearer {axcessToken}");`

instead this worked for me

`client.AddDefaultHeader("Authorization", $"Bearer {axcessToken}");`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the Authenticator.
First, you should decorate the controller or the action like below:

```
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = "Bearer")]
public class ApiServiceController : Controller
{
}
```

or better than that:

```
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
public class ApiServiceController : Controller
{
}
```

Then you should add token bearer as this line:

```
request.AddParameter("Authorization", $"Bearer {OAuthToken}", ParameterType.HttpHeader);
```

where OAuthToken is the value of the received token from login.

If you need more codes, just tell me ;)

Answer (score 0):

Question is old but for any one coming to this again.. this is what worked for me:
My project was configured to use **Https**, and I was not sending an **Https** request so server was sending me back a response informing that I should be using a **Https** request instead. After that, RestSharp performs **automatically** a redirect using Https this time, but is not including the Authorization Header. Mor infor here: https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/issues/414

My solutions was just to change my web api Url to use Https
https://.../api/values

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will help anyone, but in my case the problem was JWT issue time.  I was using current time, and the server was a few seconds behind.  I noticed that the JWT token was working when I was stepping through the code, but not when I was running it without pausing.  I fixed the problem by subtracting 1 minute from JWT issue time.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
var client = new RestClient(URL);
client.AddDefaultHeader("Authorization", string.Format("Bearer {0}", accessToken));
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue in ASP.NET Framework.  Using the AddParameter, as below, worked.

```
RestClient client = new RestClient(Url);
RestRequest request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
request.AddParameter("token", _OsiApiToken);
request.AddParameter("value", value);
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
```

Prior to the above (working version) I had the Url as...

```
String.Format("https://myorg.locator.com/arcgis/rest/services/something/?token={0}&amp;value={1}", X, Y)
```

Strangely the latter String.Format() worked in one project but not in another.  Weird.